# Confusion regarding convergence and continuity in a normed vector space.

Tags: real-analysis

I have a couple questions regarding convergence and continuity in a normed vector space, specifically a normed vector space equipped with the supremum norm.

1. Does it make sense to talk about pointwise/uniform convergence in a norm or is it only convergence in a norm or not convergence in a norm?
2. What about continuity, can a function be uniformly continuous with respect to a norm or is it again simply that norm continuity might imply uniform continuity or vice versa?

I think the answer to question 1 is that it does not make sense, but question 2 I'm not sure about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Pointwise convergence corresponds to $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ for all $ x\in X$ and is equivalent to the product topology. If $X$ is infinite dimensional, there is no norm that corresponds to this topology. Uniform convergence ($\sup_{x \in X}||f_n(x)-f(x)||\rightarrow 0$) corresponds to the topology of compact convergence. So in function spaces, pointwise convergence is not the same thing as uniform convergence, and pointwise convergence cannot even be defined in terms of a norm in function spaces.
2. I am not sure what you mean; maybe I'm just misunderstanding the words? There are results like this: "Let $Y$ be a metric space. The compact convergence topology on $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ does not depend on the metric of $Y$. Therefore if $X$ is compact, the uniform topology on $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ does not depend on the metric of $Y$." that describe that when structures give equivalent results. Or there's the elementary result that continuous functions on compact spaces are uniformly continuous. The norm on $X$ matters, since it describes which points are close together, and a uniform bound on those distances is required to establish uniform continuity. Properties like uniform convergence actually belong to the concept of Uniform Spaces, which generalizes topological and metric spaces ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space ); maybe that's part of the confusion, if the question is, "where does the property of uniformness come from?"

Another way of stating the question might be, "If there is a norm $||\cdot||_X$ such that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is uniformly continuous, is $f$ uniformly continuous for any norm?" Well, if $X$ is finite dimensional, like $\mathbb{R}^N$ with $N$ finite, all norms are equivalent ( [https://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.335/norm-equivalence.pdf](https://math.mit.edu/%7Estevenj/18.335/norm-equivalence.pdf) ), so you can rescale the unit ball to get one successful uniform continuity proof to work for any other norm.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is this: can a function in a vector space be uniformly continuous independently of the norm?

Comment: Does the update about equivalent norms help?

Comment: Yes, thank you.